# Solidity 0.4, send ether through smart contract

Tags: solidity, msg.sender

I am struggling to find how to send ether value through a smart contract on the version of solidity 0.4. I know by experience that we can use:

`contract.deposit{value: 1 ether}();`

from the version 0.6 and above but I can't really find its ancestor.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Solidity v0.4, below syntax should work:

```
contract.deposit.value(1 ether)();
```

Hope this helps.